# rfe function in the caret R package and external resampling validation implementation

Tags: r, classification, feature-selection, caret

Based on an excellent and very useful discussion on a previous question i posted ([How can I use synthetic data to validate my classification model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/249298/how-can-i-use-synthetic-data-to-validate-my-classification-model/249457?noredirect=1#comment477896_249457)), i would like to ask a very specific question about the rfe function of the R package caret which performs recursive feature elimination:

in detail, based on the above link and the discussion regarding the potential selection-bias and overfitting concerning the recursive feature elimination, does the actual function of rfe performs the external validation of the feature selection as illustrated in the Algorithm 2 in section 18.2 of the caret tutorial ?
[**http://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html**]

Of course, It is mentioned below of the above section that:

"*The resampling-based Algorithm 2 is in the rfe function. Given the potential selection bias issues, this document focuses on rfe*.."

Overall, in order to summarize my question and if i have understood the methodology behind the rfe implemented in caret:

rfe indeed performs the external resampling for validation of the selected features, and it is **valid for just using a data set of small sample size as a total training set/input set** ? with the final goal of possibly finding common selected features in different random seeds ? (not the repeats of cross-validation in the rfe function)? In other words, if after 10 different random seeds-with 10-fold repeated cross-validation/5 repeats-, some features appeared constantly in all iterations, these would be suggested as features with "increased role in the system under evaluation" ?

A small code chunk example:

library(caret)

library(foreach)

ctrl <- rfeControl(functions = rfFuncs,method = "repeatedcv",
repeats = 5, verbose = FALSE)

feature.list <- foreach(i=1:20)%do% {

set.seed(i)

rfProfile <- rfe(x,y=,sizes = 50, rfeControl = ctrl) #arbitary set size

final.subset <-predictors(rfProfile)

}

stable.hub.signature <- Reduce(intersect,feature.list)

Thus, to conclude in the above code my first question is correct about the external resampling validation ?

And generally this kind of feature selection is biased when using these features to train the same dataset that was used for the feature selection, correct ?